# serialization using c#

Tags: c#, security, serialization

Can serialization be used as a secure means to store the state of program?

Comment: can you explain a little more please

Comment: the purpose of serialization is not security, so think about encryption.

Comment: What attack would that defend against?

Answer (score 4):

No, Serialization is just a technology to allow you to convert in-memory representations of objects or object graphs into a stream of bytes that can later (with the type definitions),  be reconstituted back into the in-memory representation of the same objects.  If you want some kind of security you could encrypt the stream of bytes before you persist (store) it to disk or to a database, and then decrypt it again before you de-serialize it, but the Serialzation/Deserialization process itself provides no security.

Answer (score 1):

Nice excerpt from [wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)

> Serialization, however, breaks the
>   opacity of an abstract data type by
>   potentially exposing private
>   implementation details. To discourage
>   competitors from making compatible
>   products, publishers of proprietary
>   software often keep the details of
>   their programs' serialization formats
>   a trade secret. Some deliberately
>   obfuscate or even encrypt the
>   serialized data.

Another words, serialization in itself is not secure at all, since it can potentially *expose* data rather than obfuscate or hide data. Human-readable serialization probably makes this dilemma worse.

As a totally side note, may I suggest looking at protocol buffers rather than serialization?

http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/faq.html

[Protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)

[Also: Jon Skeet's C# port of the protocol buffers (from Java, I believe...)](http://github.com/jskeet/dotnet-protobufs)

Answer (score 0):

+1 for @Charles' explanation.

If you're saving application settings on a per-user basis you should use the `ProtectedData` class from the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace to securely store the serialized data; use the `DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser` scope for per-user data.

The `ProtectedData` class encrypts the data using the user's login password; the underlying `DPAPI` code handles password changes so the data can still be accessed.